# Making prediction in SavedModel from BigQuery ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I trained a Logistic Regression model on Bigquery and downloaded it locally.
Afterwards I wanted to load it and make a prediction but it gives me an error which I cannot solve.

This is the simple code I've written. In particular, query contains the predictors (I've read to submit them in JSON, that's why I've encoded them like this) and I added .signatures['serving_default'] since otherwise it gives me an error, i.e. 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.saved_model.load('./log_reg')

query = [{
    "pcoordinate_x": "11.191853",
    "pcoordinate_y": "45.892605",
    "mvalue": "0",
    "pcode": "IT*TNK*ETN046",
    "porigin": "route220",
    "scode": "IT*TNK*ETN046-IT*TNK*ETN046",
    "pmetadata_provider": "Route220",
    "pmetadata_accessType": "PRIVATE_WITHPUBLICACCESS",
    "pmetadata_capacity": "1",
    "pmetadata_categories": "['EAT&CHARGE']",
    "smetadata_outlets_outletTypeCode": "Schuko",
    "smetadata_outlets_maxPower": "3.7",
    "smetadata_outlets_maxCurrent": "0.0",
    "smetadata_outlets_minCurrent": "0.0",
    "mvalue_p": "0.0",
    "mvalue_t": "13.3",
    "season": "2",
    "altitude": "1440.0",
    "hour": "09",
    "day": "12",
    "month": "09"
  }]

model.signatures['serving_default'](query)
```

Running the code now it gives me this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQwq0.png)
Has someone been able to make a prediction with their model and can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Python is expecting this be called as:

model.signatures['serving_default'](pcoordinate_x = 11.191853, pcoordinate_y = 45.892605, mvalue=0, ...)